# JTable: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a problem when I called this function. I created a JTable and I want it to show data from ArrayList. Please, help me to solve it!

```
 private void LoadData() 

{
        String[] columns = new String [] { "Ho", "Tenlot", "Ten", "Ma", "NgSinh", "Dia Chi", "Phai","Luong", "MaNVQL", "Phong" };

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(null , columns);
        ArrayList<CLSNhanVien> ds = new ArrayList<CLSNhanVien>();
        ds = NHANVIENDAO.NhanVienDAO.layDanhSachNhanVien();

        for (int i = 0; i <ds.size(); i++)
        {
            String ho = ds.get(i).getHONV();
            String tenlot = ds.get(i).getTENLOT();
            String ten = ds.get(i).getTENNV();
            String ma = ds.get(i).getMANV();
            Date ns = ds.get(i).getNGAYSINH();
            String dchi = ds.get(i).getDIACHI();
            String phai = ds.get(i).getPHAI();
            float luong = ds.get(i).getLUONG();
            String manvql = ds.get(i).getMA_NQL();
            int phg = ds.get(i).getPHONG();
             Object[] items = new Object[] {ho, tenlot, ten, ma, ns, dchi, phai, luong, manvql, phg};
                model.addRow(items);
        }


        jTable1.setRowHeight(30);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(70);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(70);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(70);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(70);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(200);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(200);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(70);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(70);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(70);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setPreferredWidth(70);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an empty ArrayList... try adding an object manually in your array and in your model... and refactor this way

```
for (CLSNhanVien element : ds)
{

    String ho = element.getHONV();
    String tenlot = element.getTENLOT();
    String ten = element.getTENNV();
    String ma = element.getMANV();
    Date ns = element.getNGAYSINH();
    String dchi = element.getDIACHI();
    String phai = element.getPHAI();
    float luong = element.getLUONG();
    String manvql = element.getMA_NQL();
    int phg = element.getPHONG();
     Object[] items = new Object[] {ho, tenlot, ten, ma, ns, dchi, phai, luong, manvql, phg};
        model.addRow(items);
}
```